# Node function recursion with Twitter API

Tags: node.js, recursion, twitter

I'm working on a NodeJS app that will count a Twitter user's tweets between two dates. I have it working for a set of dates that contain less than the 200 count maximum specified by the Twitter API. However, I'm having trouble making the second call to the API recursive, which would allow me to get more than 200 by making multiple calls.

```
module.exports = function (user, start, end, callback) {
  var Twitter = require('twitter');
  var client = new Twitter({
   // keys
  });

  var max_id = null;
  getTweets(start, user, max_id, t => {

    /*
     * DO STUFF (set up dates, calculate, and filter t to dates between start and end
     */

    callback({
      user: user,
      tweets: t.length,
      startdate: start.toLocaleDateString(),
      enddate: end.toLocaleDateString(),
      totaldays: totaldays,
      average: average
    });
  }); // End getTweets call

  function getTweets(s, u, m, cb) {
   var options = {
      screen_name: u, 
      count: 200, 
      result_type: "recent", 
      trim_user: 1,
      include_rts: 1
    };
    if (m != null) options.max_id = m;

    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', options, (e,t,r) => {
      if (e) console.error(e); 
      var oldest = t[t.length - 1];
      console.log(oldest.created_at + " | " + s);

      if (new Date(oldest.created_at) > new Date(s)) {
        console.log("recursing...");
        getTweets(s, u, oldest.id, x => t = t.concat(x));
      } else {
        console.log("Got tweets, executing callback");
        cb(t);
      }
    });
  } // End getTweets function
} // End module.exports function
```

If I enter dates with <200 tweets, it works fine. When I hit the recursion condition however, it hangs and the console shows:

```
Tue Aug 15 19:14:31 +0000 2017 | 2017-08-08
recursing...
Thu Jul 27 20:44:54 +0000 2017 | 2017-08-08
Got tweets, executing callback
```

But no results, it just hangs. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, a good night's rest and a fresh look showed me the answer. Instead of trying to run the callbacks up and back down the stack, I now pass the data to the top of the stack and execute the original callback from there. Thusly:

```
getTweets([], start, user, max_id, t => {
```

...

```
 function getTweets(t, s, u, m, cb) {
```

...

```
 client.get('statuses/user_timeline', options, (err,twt,res) => {
  if (err) console.error(err); 
  t = t.concat(twt);

  if (new Date(oldest.created_at) > new Date(s)) {
    console.log("getting more...");
    getTweets(t, s, u, oldest.id, cb) ;

  } else {
    console.log("Got tweets, executing callback");
    cb(t);
  }
```

...

Works perfectly! Hope this helps someone.